# copying one array to another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am an array in following format. I am reading following data from a file `data.json` like this

```
$.getJSON('data/data.json', function (ids) {
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var id = ids[i];
                teams = id;
                $('<li>' + id + '</li>').appendTo(span);

            }
        });
```

here is data

```
[
"109 200",
"109 201",
"102 202",
"103 202"
]
```

So what I want is to copy this array to another lets say `c` but in following form

```
[
"109",
"109",
"102",
"103",
"200",
"201",
"202",
"202"
]
```

How can I do this using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Ahmed's answer is the least amount of code and it is working.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: No, the result is not in the order that OP requires.

Comment: @João: I see now. You are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Iterate** over the result set, **split** each element by whitespace, and **add** the resulting two numbers to two different arrays, each representing one halve, and finally,  **concatenate** the left part with the right part:

```
var left = [], 
    right = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  var pair = ids[i].split(" ");
  left.push(pair[0]);
  right.push(pair[1]);
}
var result = left.concat(right);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that will get the ordering OP wanted. With the edit, it does. ;)

Comment: No problem. I'm just too bad at ECMAScript to be able to supply the correct solution so I'm glad you could.

Answer (score 3):

simply use

```
ids.join(' ').split(' ');
```

**Edit**
This will respect the order.

```
$.map(ids,function(i){ return i.split(' ')[0]; }).concat($.map(ids,function(i){ return i.split(' ')[1]; }))
```

Comment: +1 Very very nice and short solution. Seems to work just right keeping the order and splitting them up: http://jsfiddle.net/6rgd3/

Comment: But it doesn't keep the order that OP requires.

Answer (score 1):

Although João has the correct method to do this, I noticed the order in which you wanted these elements adding to the array. To get what you state you're after, try this:

```
$.getJSON('data/data.json', function (ids) {
    var leftArray = new Array();
    var rightArray = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var splitted = ids[i].split(" ");

        if (splitted[0] !== null) {
            leftArray.push(splitted[0]);
        }

        if (splitted[1] !== null) {
            rightArray.push(splitted[1]);
        }
    }

    // now join the two arrays together to get your order
    var joinedArray = leftArray.conact(rightArray);

    // now build your elements with the data
    for (var i = 0; i < joinedArray.length; i++) {
        $('<li>' + joinedArray[i] + '</li>').appendTo(span);
    }
});
```